# Is comparing two images in VB.NET by compairing their byte-arrays valid?

Tags: arrays, .net, vb.net, image, compare

I need to compare two images and find out if they are equal (imagewise not reference).

So I took this approach:

```
Public Function ToArray(ByRef img As Image) As Byte()
    Dim m As New MemoryStream
    img.Save(m, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    Return m.ToArray()
End Function
```

I first convert both images into byte arrays and then:

```
Public Function ValEquals(ByRef orig As Image, ByRef toCompareTo As Image) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = True

    Dim orig_arr() As Byte = ToArray(orig)
    Dim toCompareTo_arr() As Byte = ToArray(toCompareTo)

    If orig_arr.Count = toCompareTo_arr.Count Then
        For i As Int64 = 0 To orig_arr.Count - 1
            If orig_arr(i) <> toCompareTo_arr(i) Then
                result = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Else
        result = False
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Compare both arrays byte by byte if they are equal.

Is that a valid way to find out if both images are equal?

I saw different approaches where people take the image and compare each pixel like [this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_compare.html).

Which is better or more correct?

Thx ^~^

Comment: If one image is true color and another uses a palette, but their pixels are identical, do you consider them different?

Comment: I think comparing their hash would be faster.

Comment: @CruleD It would, but I compare a local image with one fetched from my db and some properties changed, tho those do not effect the outcome of the comparison and I think getHashCode would return false even if both are equal.

Comment: @GSerg But does a byte-array differentiate between #000 and f.e. Color.Black. I doubt that, since palettes are converted to #-colors anyway.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Color.Black` in the [BMP format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) to which you are serializing the images. There is a big difference in binary representation between true color BMPs and paletted BMPs. You need to understand what and why you are doing, then you will figure if it is enough to compare resulting pixel data, or the way of representing that pixel data is also important.